# Token-based authentication with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, cookies, token

I have a problem with authentication using JWT.

1. On the most website, when I check remember-me option,

   - the token may be stored in localStroage, or cookie. This is easy.
2. If I don't check remember-me option and logged in,

   - I will lose the logged-in status when I close the browser. This is not a problem either.
   - But when I just open new tab or reload current tab (without clicking Logout button), I am still logged in.

For second case, how can it be possible if I use only sessionStorage or variable in javascript. I read many answers in this site, but couldn't get what I need.
I thought using xsrf token or timestamp on token. 
Or Is there any way to detect browser closing and remove cookie? (like callback function).

Thank you for reading.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't setup timeout of cookies, they are cleared on browser close, so you just need to store your data in cookies

Comment: @monkeyinsight If I don't setup timeout of cookies, does it stay stored when I click refresh button of browser?

Comment: @monad98 they should